# not able to retrieve data from database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I have retrieved data from one table but I'm not able to retrieve the data from another table. The view part is not working. Due to some reason the PDF is displaying blank (using tcpdf). Can we fetch it as array? If yes, then how can we fetch it as array?Some of the data appears to be printed below the button that I press.It does not display on the pdf that is generated after the we click on the button.

code :

controller

```
index(){
    $this->load->database();  
    //load the model  
    $this->load->model('Order_model');  
    //load the method of model  
    $data['h']=$this->Order_model->select();  
    //return the data in view  
    $this->load->view('includes/orderPdf', $data);   
}
```

model

```
public function select()  
{  
   //data is retrive from this query  
   $query = $this->db->get('master_user');  
   return $query;  
}
```

view

```
<?php  
     foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
     {  
        ?><tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row->mobile_no ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row->country ?></td>  
        </tr>  
     <?php }  
     ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($h)` in view.what do you see?

Comment: nothing.It is still blank and not opening in form of pdf

Answer (score 0):

Best way to set up is probably similar to:

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('Order_model', 'Order');
$data['orders'] = $this->Order->getOrder();
```

Model:

```
public function getOrder() {
    $q = $this->db->get('master_user');
    return $q->num_rows() ? $q->result_array() : [];
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($orders as $order) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$order['mobile_no']?></td>
        <td><?=$order['country']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Now you can also add an `if(empty($orders))` and put in "no orders to show" or similar.

Comment: While I completely agree this is a better way of doing things the only real difference here between this code and the users is that you check `num_rows()` ... so unless the database is empty the user will still have issues for whatever reason.

Comment: @Alex indeed, my edit didn't save earlier, he asks if results can be gathered as an array (at least from my translation) and as such I meant to provide that solution. The reason behind his code not working is either empty DB or other errors in his script.

Comment: Can we use 2D array's to retrive data?i.e like $order[0]['mobile_no']

Comment: @Ked with my answer, you could indeed do $orders[0]['mobile_no'] (However this would cause an error if you had no orders) But if you use the if statement I provided above that should solve that issue.